# WaitForDebugger in Mac application

Tags: xcode, macos

I am working on a MAC application. I am debugging an issue when my program is started by another application (i.e. not inside xcode).

Can I add code in my application, someething like 'WaitforDegger' in android, where my applicatin will paue until I attached it with xcode debugger before it continues?

Comment: Edit Scheme > Run > Info > Launch > "Wait for the executable to be launched"

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing like that built in. You can put in some code like this (C or Objective-C):

```
volatile int loop = 1;
while (loop)
    sleep(1);
```

Once you've attached with the debugger and selected that frame of that thread, you can set `loop` to 0 and continue:

```
expr loop=0
cont
```

You'll need to compile with debug symbols in order for the debugger to see the `loop` symbol, but I figure you're already doing that since you're trying to debug, anyway.

Comment: "*There's nothing like that built in*" see nextman's comment & my answer.

Comment: Neither of those is programmatic, like `WaitForDebugger()`. They can also miss very early startup of the target.

Comment: "Attach to process by PID or name " doesn't let the app launch until debugger is attached.

Comment: That's simply not true. In fact, it can miss the entire lifetime of short-lived processes. In one shell, launch `lldb` and issue the command `process attach -w -n true`. In another shell, run `/usr/bin/true`. In all probability, `true` will exit before the debugger has a chance to attach.

Answer (score 0):

Debug menu > Attach to process by PID or name ... > Write the name of the app you want to attach it to. It will wait for the app to be launched.

Launch the app. Make sure that there are not other instances of the app running.

---

Another way is to launch the app in a script and sent it to background `(<launch-command> &);`, immediately find the PID of the app via `pgrep` and send a `kill -STOP PID` signal.

After you've attached the debugger to the app, send a `-CONT` signal.